# Denormalize a type by its property and property type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a simple type

```
interface Person {
  name: string
  age: number
  character: {
    spending: number
  }
}
```

I wish to create the following type through type manipulations instead of manual union like below

```
type DenormalizedPerson =
  | { field: 'name'; value: string }
  | { field: 'age'; value: string }
  | { field: 'character'; value: { spending: number } }
```

Comment: I don't think the syntax you shared works with Typescript 2.x

Answer (score 2):

Typescript does not let you tie two independent properties by key... directly. Instead, you may create an intermediate type before de-normalizing.

```
interface Person {
    name: string
    age: number
    character: {
      spending: number
    }
  }
  
  type DenormalizedPerson = {
    [p in keyof Person]: {
      field: p
      value: Person[p]
    }
  }[keyof Person]
```

Comment: You can slightly reduce your solution. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/N7O4DN). No need to use `& string`. `keyof` operator always returns only allowed keys

Comment: Great! thank you.. the final `[keyof Person]` was exactly what I was aiming for but I was immaturely trying to deconstruct the inner definition.